# Deprecation of https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me and how properly to migrate

Tags: google-plus

Recently **Google plus** is pending for shutdown, which also shutdown some **Google Plus API** including this one `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` which our service is actively using.

That above API was used in one of our legacy login library, which I can't even find the source for it. Hence I am now trying to patch it myself.

Reading the migrate [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide) from Google, it doens't tell much in terms of how to change the url.

Referencing some open source library like [1](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/pac4j-3.5.0/pac4j-oauth/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oauth/profile/google2/Google2ProfileDefinition.java), [2](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/1024). I have come up with the fix of replacing the url `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` with `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`, which works but `oauth2/v3/userinfo` lacks documentation, so I am pretty worry that `oauth2/v3/userinfo` is not intended to be used like the above.

So my question is:

1. Is my solution: change `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` with `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo` an intended migration, if not then how can I migrate out of Google Plus API?
2. Any documentation on `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`? The closest I can find is [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery), which seems more like an brief intro then a documentation.

Comment: Update on 2019: Still using `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`, it is working fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "/oauth2/v3/userinfo" call will not be deprecated on March 7th, 2019 as it is not part of the Google + API.

If you look at the Google Developers Console, those calls are not registered as part of the Google + API.

From Google email:

> If you are directly requesting the “plus.me” scope, any other Google+
>   OAuth scopes, or making any Google+ API calls, please ensure that you
>   remove these requests from your project before March 7, 2019.

Comment: Awesome, so other also found the same result as I do, so I think it is save to use `/oauth2/v3/userinfo`, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody answer, I think I will give out the best info I can gather...

For 1. Supported by multiple open source project. [Pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/issues/1228), [hybridauth](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/1024). It seems like the method of change https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me with https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo is the best you can do to fix this issue.

For 2. Still no detail documentation for that